# how to use regexpr to identify patters in icd10 data

Tags: r

I am working with icd10 data, and I wish to create new variables called complication based on the pattern "E1X.9X", using regular expression but I keep getting an error. please help

```
dm_2$icd9_9code<- (E10.49, E11.51, E13.52, E13.9, E10.9, E11.21, E16.0)

dm_2$DM.complications<- "present"
dm_2$DM.complications[regexpr("^E\\d{2}.9$",dm_2$icd9_code)]<- "None"

# Error in dm_2$DM.complications[regexpr("^E\\d{2}.9", dm_2$icd9_code)] <- 
# "None" : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I want

```
icd9_9code     complications
E10.49          present
E11.51          present
E13.52          present
E13.9           none
E10.9           none
E11.21          present
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem has already been solved. The 'icd' R package which me and co-authors have been maintaining for five years can do this. In particular, it uses standardized sets of comorbidities, including the diabetes with complications you seek, from AHRQ, Elixhauser original, Charlson, etc..

E.g., for ICD-10 AHRQ, you can see the codes for diabetes with complications here. From icd 4.0, these include ICD-10 codes from the WHO, and all years of ICD-10-CM.

```
icd::icd10_map_ahrq$DMcx
```

To use them, first just take your patient data frame and try:

```
library(icd)
pts <- data.frame(visit_id = c("encounter-1", "encounter-2", "encounter-3", 
"encounter-4", "encounter-5", "encounter-6"), icd10 = c("I70401", 
"E16", "I70.449", "E13.52", "I70.6", "E11.51"))
comorbid_ahrq(pts)
# and for diabetes with complications only:
comorbid_ahrq(pts)[, "DMcx"]
```

Or, you can get a data frame instead of a matrix this way:

```
comorbid_ahrq(pts, return_df = TRUE)
# then you can do:
comorbid_ahrq(pts, return_df = TRUE)$DMcx
```

If you give an example of the source data and your goal, I can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there are a few errors in your code, I'll note them in the code below:

You'll want to start with wrapping your ICD codes with quotes:  `"E13.9"`

```r
dm_2 <- data.frame(icd9_9code = c("E10.49", "E11.51", "E13.52", "E13.9", "E10.9", "E11.21", "E16.0"))
```

Next let's use `grepl()` to search for the particular ICD pattern. Make sure you're applying it to the proper column, your code above is attempting to use `dm_2$icd9_code` and not `dm_2$icd9_9code`:

```r
dm_2$DM.complications <- "present"
dm_2$DM.complications[grepl("^E\\d{2}.9$", dm_2$icd9_9code)] <- "None"
```

Finally,

```r
dm_2
#>   icd9_9code DM.complications
#> 1     E10.49          present
#> 2     E11.51          present
#> 3     E13.52          present
#> 4      E13.9             None
#> 5      E10.9             None
#> 6     E11.21          present
#> 7      E16.0          present
```

A quick side note -- there is a wonderful ICD package you may find handy as well: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icd/index.html